# gst.h no such file or directory

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am trying to compile a gstreamer plugin for android. The plugin has 
    #include<`gst/gst.h`>

And, I have also added the path of gst.h to Android.mk. But still when I compile using mm command, I get the error "gst.h  no such file or directory".

What is the correct way to include the path to the header file in Android.mk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the instructions correctly. You don't need to add extra paths to Android.mk. Please take another look how the other plugin packages are integrated. Ideally include a link to where you host the code for your plugin here (if you can).